# Program to automatically get orders from a Magento site and print from desktop

Tags: windows, magento

I'm looking for some sort of Windows desktop client that can query or receive new orders from a Magento site and print out the order.

To be specific, this is a restaurant site (running [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento)) where we'd like the orders placed online to go straight to our receipt printer so we can process it (get the food ready) immediately.

Currently we have the orders come by email to Outlook (that checks every minute for new email), which then runs a rule to print it, but we've had many issues with this set up, from not being able to format the printout to our liking, to sometimes not getting emails etc.

Comment: Why not make your website send a mail in the formatting you require, and use your existing setup then?

Comment: Thanks, that's true, but I'd still rather avoid the email medium if possible and get data directly from the site.

Comment: I'm afraid without knowing the structure it's hard to give an answer to that. Is it some known standard setup (including a known standard web-app) where the orders are made with on your site? Or are you asking for both components (the User GUI to enter orders on your site, with the matching "poller" on your Windows machine at the restaurant)? In that case we might need some data on your server as well: what kind of "web-apps" can you install/use there?

Comment: We use magento if that's what you mean by web-app.

Comment: Yes, that helps! Even I have heard of it (though I don't really know it). I've integrated that directly with your question. That should enable those knowing Magenta to hopefully give you some recommendations. I'm leaving the scene now – and the answers to those who know :) Good luck!